# What is the name of the operation $v^T H v$?

Tags: linear-algebra

To find out how something is called is the one thing I don't know how to use Google for.

If I have a vector $v$ and a symmetric matrix $H$, then the operation $v^T H v$ gives me some sort of projection of the matrix $H$ on the vector $v$. For example if $H$ is the Hessian, the operation gives me the second derivative in the direction of $v$.

What is the name of this operation?

Comment: It is called a symmetric bilinear form I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $(u,v) \mapsto u^T H v$ is called a bilinear form. It is called a symmetric bilinear form if $H$ is symmetric. It is called an inner product if $H$ is symmetric positive definite.
- $v \mapsto v^T H v$ is called a quadratic form.
- You might also be interested in $v \mapsto \frac{v^T H v}{v^T v}$ which is called a Rayleigh quotient.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful! The Rayleigh quotient is what I was after. I didn't think the normalization for the vector length was relevant. I just spent half an hour reading up on the inner product, I didn't know you could stick a matrix in the middle and still call it an inner product. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo:  Note that the quadratic form $v^T H v$ depends only on the *symmetric part* of $H$, because if we split $H = \frac 1 2 (H+H^T) + \frac 1 2 (H-H^T)$ into the symmetric and antisymmetric parts, then the antisymmetric part contributes only zero to the result.